# I want API JSON response data but don't want it to be shown in network tab as its not specific to logged in user yet very sensitive?

Tags: reactjs, api, security, response, secure-coding

So basically I have some information which I have gathered with lot of effort, this information is not specific to user so I cannot totally depend on my user logged in token, this is somewhat some generic info that needs to be present on the website as info and currently this information is coming directly as JSON from API calls in network tab which makes me insecure that this info can be copied and used by 3 person without my concern.

What can I do to stop this ?

Answer (score 0):

The only foolproof way to keep the client from possibly being able to see and possibly manipulate sensitive information is to not send it to the client in the first place. There's no other way. While you can make it harder for the client to do so by, for example, encrypting on the server and decrypting on the client side inside long, convoluted, minified code - it's still possible.

If each user has information specific to them that you'd like to display, the right approach would be to validate the client's login token and then send back the data for that user (but not the data for any other user). If the client sees that the information is incorrect (like if someone else was using the computer), you can prompt them to log out and log back in with their actual credentials, resulting in another request that'll be verified by the server and which will return the data needed to display what the user is looking for.

If you're worried about third-party snoopers, you should also, of course, use SSL on your site. (Unfortunately there's not much you can do about other vulnerabilities the client may have, such as malicious browser extensions, drivers, and hardware - either don't send the info in the first place, or bear the small risk.)